# Ionic loading process happening long time when bad net connection

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

when the net connection is very slow, loading process happening long time in login page. Its never ending process. how can i solve this?

This is my controller code

```
$scope.doLogin = function() {
    $ionicLoading.show();
    $http.post(syncData.url+'users/loginuser', $scope.loginData).success(function(data){
        $ionicLoading.hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: May be you catch error in `errorHandler` and present user bad net connection error.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a errorHandler for `$http.post`, but remind the `err` depends on your server side:

```
$scope.doLogin = function() {
  $ionicLoading.show();
  $http.post(syncData.url+'users/loginuser', $scope.loginData).then(function(data){
    //handle data
    $ionicLoading.hide();
  }, function(err) {
    //handle err
    $ionicLoading.hide();
  });
});
```

Hope this will help, regards!